# (angular 8) sending file data in $http Post data gives {} on rails API logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, ruby-on-rails-5, angular8, angular-file-upload

**angular 8, Rails 5.2 API**

I am trying to attach an image to my `Event` model in edit form. I am following [this tutorial](https://netbasal.com/how-to-implement-file-uploading-in-angular-reactive-forms-89a3fffa1a03)

my **typescript code:**

```
const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8; multipart/form-data',
    Authorization: environment.apiAuthKey,
  })
};
updateEvent(event: Event): Observable<Event> {
    return this.http.put<Event>(url, event, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
   ...
 }
```

This generates these logs on Rails API side:

```
Started PUT ...
Processing by ... as JSON
  Parameters: {"title"=>"testing image", "image" => {}}
...
```

Any idea why image param is being null?

So far, from my research I got an idea that I have to put multipart-formdata in my HTTP headers, I did that but no change in output.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use   `formData` instead of `FormGroup`

```
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('image', image);
formData.append('title', testing image);
this.http.post(url, formData);
```

you can also do a test to post  without setting HttpHeaders, FormData will set the suitable header for you